# Searching for a integer in a list (Lisp)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I cannot think of a way to search a list to make sure it has all integers. I want to immediately return `nil` if there is non-integer data, and continue my function if there is not.

The recursive function I am trying to make will `cons` the `car` with the `cdr` of the list. With the attempts I have made, I am not able to return `nil`. I have only been able to ignore the non-integer data.  E.g., `(add-1-all '(1 2 3 a))` will return `(2 3 4)` after adding one to each number.

```
    (defun add-1-all (L) 
            (if (null L) 
                L
              (if (integerp (car L))
                  (cons (+ (car L) 1) (add-1-all (cdr L)))
                  nil)))
```

I do understand that the cons is making this happen, as the recursion is adding on to the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first sentence,

> I cannot think of a way to search a list in Lisp to make sure it has all integers.

makes it sound like you want to *check* whether a list is all integers.  You can *check* whether a list is all integers using [`every`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm):

```
CL-USER> (every 'integerp '(1 2 3 4))
;=> T
CL-USER> (every 'integerp '(1 2 a 4))
;=> NIL
```

`every` will take care of short-circuiting, i.e., returning `nil` as soon as the first element failing the predicate is found.

However, your code makes it sound like you want to map over a list, collecting the value of a function applied to each integer and returning the collected values, except that if you encounter a non-integer, you return null.  Perhaps the easiest way to do this is using the [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) macro.  A solution looks almost identical to the English specification:

```
CL-USER> (loop for x in '(1 2 3 4)
            if (not (integerp x)) return nil
            else collect (1+ x))

;=> (2 3 4 5)
CL-USER> (loop for x in '(1 2 a 4)
            if (not (integerp x)) return nil
            else collect (1+ x))

;=> NIL
```

Doing this with `loop` also has some advantages over a recursive solution.  While some languages in the Lisp family (e.g., Schema) require tail call optimization, and some Common Lisp implementations do it too, it's not required in Common Lisp.  As a result, it can be safer (e.g., you won't run out of stack space) if you use an iterative solution (e.g., with `loop`) rather than a recursive (even a tail-recursive) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use a helper function, and for that helper function to carry the answer along with it as it recurses, so that it can discard the whole thing at any time if necessary. Incidentally, this will also be [tail recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), meaning that it can deal with extremely long lists without running out of stack space.

```
(defun add-1-all (L) 
  (add-1-all-helper L nil))

(defun add-1-all-helper (L answer)
  (if (null L)
    answer
    (if (integerp (car L))
      (add-1-all-helper
        (cdr L)
        (cons (+ (car L) 1) answer)))))
```

Comment: That makes sense. Would there be a way to do this without a helper function?

Comment: You could write a function that takes a variable number of arguments, and behaves like `add-1-all` if it got 1 argument, and `add-1-all-helper` if it got 2. Or you could write `add-1-all-helper` in a `let` inside `add-1-all`, if you were just concerned about polluting your namespace.

Comment: @NeilForrester You forgot to reverse answer. Also, you could do without helper function by using an optional argument with a default value, or with labels.